# Instagram permissions scope for Live applications

Tags: permissions, instagram

My application has just been accepted by Instagram and is now in Live status. However, when I try to use the `GET/users/self/follows` API I still get the following error:

```
{"meta": 
    {"code": 400,
     "error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException", 
     "error_message": "This client has not been approved to access this resource."
    }
}
```

After a new check of the API docs, I realized that Instagram gives just the `basic` permission to the new applications (https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/). Am I right? So, there is no way to use the other API Endpoints? If yes, whats the point in keeping the docs about not available APIs?

Comment: Did you find information about your question? I have the same problem. Thank you

Comment: @Náthali No, sorry. It seems that Instagram does not give such permissions any more.